# Riddle: Irregular math

Tags: riddle, mathematics

A numbery riddle:

> When I take five and
> add six, I get eleven,
> but when I take six and
> add seven, I get one.
> What am I?

What is the answer?

Comment: Just to warn you, this one has *definitely* been asked before - I just can't find the dup yet ;-)

Comment: Why, why, why? Everything has been asked already!

Comment: If it has been asked  before, then: Rot13(lbh ner gur ubhe unaq ba n pybpx).

Comment: https://www.pepuptheday.com/stories/when-i-take-faive-and-add-six-i-get-eleven-161/#:~:text=get%20eleven...-,When%20I%20take%20five%20and%20add%20six%2C%20I%20get%20eleven,What%20am%20I%3F&text=A%20clock!

Comment: I *finally* found it! (That took some doing...) Looks like last time it was posted an answerer thought they'd seen it somewhere on the site too but also had difficulty locating it. Phew! (And sorry to disappoint you!)

Comment: @HexagonalImpossibilities Why? Because this site has been around for over ten years now. Duplicates are inevitable after such a long time. I'd recommend that, going forward, you check to see whether a particular puzzle or riddle has already been posted before posting it.